# JBOSS 6.1 running EJB 3.1 performance issues when invoking stateful beans concurrently

Tags: jboss, ejb, javabeans, stateful

After migrating a large server application from JBOSS 4.0.5 running EJB 3.0 to JBOSS 6.1.0 running EJB 3.1 I have noticed consistent response time increase when **concurrently** (100+) accessing stateful beans and method invocation.

On several tests average response times on method invocations used to be of about several milliseconds on the older environment whilst on the newer versions the averages are around the low hundreds on an identical system with everything running locally so network problems are excluded. (Mostly setters) (SFB lookups are done locally)

How can I investigate this further what can be causing this?

Comment: This issue reproduces on a out-of-the box JBOSS 6.1 with only a few baisc Classes/SFB's (setters and such) to simulate the situation described above.

Answer (score 0):

Just my thoughts on it

life cycle of Stateful Session Bean

> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giplj.html#gipln

In Jboss Stateful Session Bean is moved from Ready to Passive state if cache becomes too full or a bean is too old.

> http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/1.0.7/html/SessionBean_and_MDB_configuration.html

I think "full cache" could be one of the cause for delay in response as it would start to passivation of stateful session beans. One way to confirm this is add debug log to PrePassivate callback function in the Stateful Session Bean and gradually stress the application observing the behaviour.

Comment: I've tried manually increasing the size of the cache to a ridiculous amount to confirm your thoughts but the issue is still there.

Comment: Also disabled passivation entirely with the @CacheConfig annotation as suggested in the docs. Didn't improve the timings